# Full Background in Pages Install / Uninstall

Tags: background, nsis

I'm new with NSIS, and the problems i have, the people of this forum can help me, and now... all the project is OK.

But now... i have one small problem... in Pages (Install / Uninstall) i have a Left Image... all OK... but... ¿Is possible the BMP can stay at the backround with 100% width and height?

The example is here:

[image: example]

How is the form to put the Background BMP image in Pages?

Thanks for all friends! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the [product](http://www.graphical-installer.com/) advertised in your screenshot to build that NSIS installer for you, or create your own custom UI with a resource editor of your liking. It's probably a good starting point to take a look at the UIs that come with NSIS, open their executables in a resource editor.

Comment: Thank you friend. But... not are a !include MUI2.nsh to put a BMP image at Full Background? Or a Custom Function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As author of Graphical Installer I can say it is more complicated than it looks :)

What you need is to create full sized picture, set it's content and refresh it on each page.

The picture you see on the Welcome/Finish page is not present on other pages so you need to create it manually (during runtime or via UI file - based on your preferences).

It looks simple but there is really much more to do and some serious NSIS skills are required.